# Prevent services from starting on boot without accessing system prior to boot

Tags: linux, systemd, services

Apologies for the poorly worded title (taking suggestions on better ones!) but I am unsure how to describe what I am trying to do. Allow me to explain the situation:

I have a number of production VMs (Google Cloud) running RockyLinux. I want to take a snapshot of these servers and then create new machines from them. The problem is when I start up these new machines they will connect to our production database and various cron jobs will start running. I do not want these two events to occur. I am wondering if there is a way to start these cloned machines and ensure none of the services in question (php-fpm, nginx, crond) will be started upon boot.

I guess an option is to put the services offline prior to the snapshot on the production machines, but I am attempting to pull this off without any service interrupts or the need for a change/maintenance request.

Comment: disabling network connections to the cloned VM may work

Comment: Similar to jstola's suggestion, the way I handle this in AWS is to set up firewall rules around the cloned machine such that only my ssh connections from my VPN can exchange network traffic with the machine.  Nothing else can reach the machine, and it can't reach anything else.  Then I log in, stop and disable the services, and take my image.